# Missing Vertices

Tags: vertices, glass, wireframe

I'm new to blender and have run into an issue trying to make a glass of liquid. I duplicated the middle of the cup to make the liquid inside and continued developing the liquid. Only when I noticed that the liquid wasn't appearing as I expected through the glass did I think there might be a problem with the glass frame itself.

[image: Wireframe of glass]

You can see that the top two rows of vertices appear as you'd expect but after those only the outer vertices are present, the inner ones have disappeared. I think I duplicated correctly in the first place but am not sure.

It appears wrong in the sense that the glass looks frosted rather than like a pure glass.

[image: Render of liquid]

My questions are: what have I possibly pressed to have caused this? And: is there any way to get these vertices back?

Comment: Is the first screenshot a wireframe of the glass and the liquid? I think you forget to duplicate the vertices before separating them.

Comment: The correct steps are `SHIFT+D` then `P>Separate by selection`. You may have forgotten to do the `SHIFT+D`.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Sounds likely. Does just `D` take a hard copy rather than a duplication? Like it re-associates those vertices with the new object, removing them from the old one? And is there any way to undo this without re-starting the whole cup?

Comment: No. `D` doesn't do anything, in 2.7 it was the shortcut for drawing in the grease pencil but now it's not assigned to any actions as far as I know. And you cannot really undo it. You can rejoin the two objects by pressing `CTRL+J` and then fill the cup back with geometry from the liquid.

Comment: Thanks @mqbakamqbaka, I have since redone the cup and recycled the liquid from the old attempt, thanks for the response!

Comment: you're welcome.